# Loading finishing before everything has loaded from multiple functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, loading

I'm sure this is going to be something really simple, but I am having a problem when calling a function which needs to do various different function calls via ajax to a .net code behind and I want to show a loader over the page until everything has finished, but its not happening.

```
function expand(ID, user) {

$('.loadingBlackSml, .loadingSml').fadeIn(1000);
checkSession();
expand2(ID, user);
$('.loadingBlackSml, .loadingSml').fadeOut(1000);
}
```

Which calls

```
function checkSession() {
return $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Test.aspx/checkForSession",
    //data: "{}",
    data: "{'idleTime':'" + clickedDT + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (sessionCheck) {
        sessionActive = JSON.stringify(sessionCheck.d);
    }
}).done(function () {
    //if session comes back as dead, redirect to restart session
    if (sessionActive == "\"false\"") {
        var url = "/Error.aspx?RefreshNeeded=true&page=" + window.location.pathname;
        $(location).attr('href', url);
    }
    //if page has gone past timeout length, try and reload it
    else if (sessionActive == "\"timeout\"") {
        var urlTO = window.location.pathname;
        $(location).attr('href', urlTO);
    }
});
}
```

and

```
function expand2(ID, user) {
return $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: '/Test.aspx/markExpanded',
    data: "{'ID':'" + ID + "', 'user':'" + user + "'}",
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
    },
    error: function ()
    { console.log('there is some error'); }

}).done(function () {
});
}
```

But the loading overlays are disappearing before it is finishing doing what its doing? I've seen something about using $.when for my calls but I'm not sure how to get this working properly?

Any advice would be great. Thanks

Comment: Just an FYI, a "code behind" is referred to as a back-end. So it has a .NET backend.

Answer (score 0):

Try to hide loading in **expand2 or checkSession function** on finish request. Like this

```
... .done(function () {
    $('.loadingBlackSml, .loadingSml').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

So loader will be hidden after everything will have finished. 
To be sure that everything is over, you can set "flag". For example check = 2. And do

```
check--; check||$('.loadingBlackSml, .loadingSml').fadeOut(1000);
```

**edited 10.04.17**

Example with flag (check) for requests

```
var check = 0; // count pending requests
function expand(ID, user) {

$('.loadingBlackSml, .loadingSml').fadeIn(1000);
count = 2;
checkSession();
expand2(ID, user);
}

function checkSession() {
return $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Test.aspx/checkForSession",
    //data: "{}",
    data: "{'idleTime':'" + clickedDT + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (sessionCheck) {
        sessionActive = JSON.stringify(sessionCheck.d);
    }
}).done(function () {
    //if session comes back as dead, redirect to restart session
    if (sessionActive == "\"false\"") {
        var url = "/Error.aspx?RefreshNeeded=true&page=" + window.location.pathname;
        $(location).attr('href', url);
    }
    //if page has gone past timeout length, try and reload it
    else if (sessionActive == "\"timeout\"") {
        var urlTO = window.location.pathname;
        $(location).attr('href', urlTO);
    }
    count--;
    if (count === 0) { // check. are all requests finished
        $('.loadingBlackSml, .loadingSml').fadeOut(1000); 
    }
});
}
function expand2(ID, user) {
return $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: '/Test.aspx/markExpanded',
    data: "{'ID':'" + ID + "', 'user':'" + user + "'}",
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
    },
    error: function ()
    { console.log('there is some error'); }

}).done(function () {
    count--;
    if (count === 0) {
        $('.loadingBlackSml, .loadingSml').fadeOut(1000); 
    }
});
}
```

Of course, you can move

```
    count--;
    if (count === 0) {
        $('.loadingBlackSml, .loadingSml').fadeOut(1000); 
    }
```

to separate function

Comment: Almost there but you can't assume that expand2() will finish after checkSession()...you really need to call a callback from both done() methods, only when both are complete can you call fadeOut()

Comment: Thanks, expand2 isn't always going to be the last function on other things called for the page. I'm a little confused about the check thing on the second part of your post?

Comment: Thanks, but the loading never seems to go away now?

Comment: It will go away. We use closure. We set count = 2. Then after each request in .done method we set count = count - 1 and compare with 0. We have 2 requests checkSession and expand2, so we will call .done twice and count will be 0 last iteration and loading will be hidden